# How to predict the class probability with an array

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, classification

I have an array of data and I'm trying to predict the probability if it's 1 or 0
I have a data set with more than 3000 rows as features and output data is either 1 or 0.

I'm quite new with neural networks, so I found an example online but now I'm having difficulties how to predict with unknown data.
In my case I want to predict the probability of 1 for **row** variable.

Here's the code

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

X = df.iloc[:,10:]
Y = df['output']
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# larger model
def create_larger():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(60, input_shape=(25,), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasClassifier(model=create_larger, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=2)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, encoded_Y, cv=kfold)
print("Larger: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
row = [[4,  0.558,  0.493,  0.954,  0.895,  0.683,  8.7,    26, 0.155,  8.3,    21.8,   0.21,   0.723,  0.548,  0.466,  0.979,  0.887,  0.464,  11.8,   25.5,   0.184,  7.5,    18, 0.217,  0.651]]
scaler = StandardScaler()
row = np.array(row)
scaled_row = pipeline.fit(row)
print(pipeline.predict(scaled_row))
```

If I run this code I get an error

```
ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got None
```

So now I'm kinda lost what to change it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, it would require more information to help you. Can you identify from which line of code the error comes from. And, are you sure your row is the same shape as your X? Then, why do you fit your pipeline on row before calling pipeline.predict?